# Google Apps error: Currently this single sign-in feature is disabled for the domain example.com

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, openid

When I try to allow a third-party tool access to my Google Apps mail, I get the error:

> Currently this single sign-in feature is disabled for the domain
>   example.com

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Note: In order to perform this in the **New Google Apps dashboard** you'll need to:

1. Login to Google Apps Control Panel as an admin
2. Select Security
3. Advanced Settings
4. Federated Login using OpenID
5. Check "Allow users to sign in to third part websites using OpenID"
6. Save changes

Answer (score 3):

OpenID authentication with Google Apps accounts are disabled by default. To change this, you need administrator rights to your Google Apps account.

Instructions for **NEW** Google Apps Control Panel

1. Login to your Google Apps Control Panel [google.com/a/example.com/] as an administrator
2. Select Security > Advanced Settings > Federated Login using OpenID
3. Check "Allow users to sign in to third part websites using OpenID"
4. Save changes

Instructions for **OLD** Google Apps Control Panel

1. Login to your Google Apps Control Panel [google.com/a/example.com/] as an administrator.
2. Go to Advanced tools > Federated Login using OpenID.
3. Check 'Allow users to sign in to third party
   websites using OpenID' and Save Changes.